# js. read page, change capitalization, slow processing time?

Tags: javascript, function, performance, text

I have a function and a list of values being compared without regard to initial capitalization, and then giving a new value to each match. processing is slow. I've been running in browser console.

here's the link to the page I am running this on
https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/matt/1?lang=eng

I also would like recognize the original pages superscripts

```
const Words = [
  {
    "name": "GOD",
    "value": "GOD"
  },{
    "name": "SAVIOR",
    "value": "SAVIOR"
  },{
    "name": "LORD",
    "value": "LORD"
  },{
    "name": "CHRIST",
    "value": "CHRIST"
  },{
    "name": "EMMANUEL",
    "value": "EMMANUEL"
  },{
    "name": "IMMANUEL",
    "value": "IMMANUEL"
  },{
    "name": "THE LORD",
    "value": "THE LORD"
  },{
    "name": "HOLY",
    "value": "HOLY"
  },{
        "name": "THE SON OF GOD",
    "value": "THE SON OF GOD"
  },{
        "name": "LAMB",
    "value": "LAMB"
  },{
    "name": "THE HOLY SPIRIT",
    "value": "THE HOLY SPIRIT"
  },{
    "name": "THE (.*)HOLY SPIRIT",
    "value": "THE HOLY SPIRIT"
  },{
    "name": " HOLY SPIRIT ",
    "value": " HOLY SPIRIT "
  },{
    "name": "THE SPIRIT",
    "value": "THE SPIRIT"
  },{
    "name": "THE SPIRIT Of TRUTH",
    "value": "THE SPIRIT Of TRUTH"
  },{
    "name": "SPIRIT ",
    "value": "SPIRIT "
  },{
    "name": "THE COMFORTER",
    "value": "THE COMFORTER"
  },{
    "name": "aCOMFORTER",
    "value": "COMFORTER"
  },{
    "name": "COMFORTER",
    "value": "COMFORTER"
  },{
    "name": "MESSIAH",
    "value": "MESSIAH"
  },{
    "name": "GOSPEL",
    "value": "GOSPEL"
  },{
    "name": "THE GOSPEL",
    "value": "THE GOSPEL"
  },{
        "name": "GabriEL",
    "value": "GabriEL"
  },{
    "name": "Life",
    "value": "Life"
  },{
        "name": "AngEL",
    "value": "AngEL"
  },{
        "name": "AngELs",
    "value": "AngELs"
  },{
    "name": "Husband",
    "value": "Husband"
  },{
    "name": "Wife",
    "value": "Wife"
  },{
    "name": "Father",
    "value": "Father"
  },{
    "name": "Mother",
    "value": "Mother"
  },{
        "name": "Children",
    "value": "Children"
  },{
    "name": "Child",
    "value": "Child"
  },{
    "name": " Son",
    "value": " Son"
  },{
    "name": " Daughter",
    "value": " Daughter"
  },{
    "name": " Thee ",
    "value": " Thee "
  },{
    "name": " Thine ",
    "value": " Thine "
  },{
    "name": " Thy ",
    "value": " Thy "
  },{
    "name": " Him ",
    "value": " Him "
  },{
    "name": " His ",
    "value": " His "
  },{
    "name": " He ",
    "value": " He "
  },{
    "name": " Her ",
    "value": " Her "
  },{
    "name": " Hers ",
    "value": " Hers "
  },{
    "name": " People ",
    "value": " People "
  },{
        "name": " We ",
    "value": " We "
  },{
    "name": "Vision",
    "value": "Vision"
  },{
    "name": "Reveal ",
    "value": "Reveal "
  },{
    "name": "Revealed ",
    "value": "Revealed "
  },{
    "name": "Faith ",
    "value": "Faith "
  },{
    "name": "Faithful",
    "value": "Faithful"
  },{
    "name": "Save",
    "value": "Save"
  },{
    "name": " Son ",
    "value": " Son "
  },{
    "name": " Sons ",
    "value": " Sons "
  },{
    "name": " Daughter ",
    "value": " Daughter "
  },{
    "name": " Daughters",
    "value": " Daughters"
  },{
    "name": " Life ",
    "value": " Life "
  },{
    "name": " Love ",
    "value": " Love "
  },{
    "name": "Tribe",
    "value": "Tribe"
  },{
    "name": "Priest",
    "value": "Priest"
  },{
    "name": "Priesthood",
    "value": "Priesthood"
  },{
    "name": "Elder",
    "value": "Elder"
  },{
        "name": "Mother",
    "value": "Mother"
  },{
    "name": "Father",
    "value": "Father"
  },{
    "name": "Brother",
    "value": "Brother"
  },{
    "name": "Sister",
    "value": "Sister"
  },{
    "name": "Daughter",
    "value": "Daughter"
  },{
    "name": "Calling",
    "value": "Calling"
  },{
    "name": "IsraEL",
    "value": "IsraEL"
  },
    {
    "name": "Transfigure",
    "value": "Transfigure"
  },{
    "name": "Birth",
    "value": "Birth"
  },{
    "name": "Daughter",
    "value": "Daughter"
  },{
    "name": "Prophet",
    "value": "Prophet"
  },{
    "name": "Prophets",
    "value": "Prophets"
  },{
    "name": "IsraEL",
    "value": "IsraEL"
  },{
    "name": "HOLY Ghost",
    "value": "HOLY SPIRIT"
  },{
    "name": "Birth",
    "value": "Birth"
  },{
        "name": "THE SON OF GOD",
    "value": "THE SON OF GOD"
  },{
    "name": "perdition",
    "value": "perdition"
  },{
    "name": "lucifer",
    "value": "lucifer"
  },{
    "name": "satan",
    "value": "satan"
  },{
    "name": "adversary",
    "value": "adversary"
  }
];

Words.forEach(word => {
 console.log(word.name);
    let reg = new RegExp(word.name, "gi");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(reg, word.value);
})
```

Comment: Why are you replacing some words with themselves? Either leave those out of the array or skip them with `if (word.name != word.value)`

Comment: My goal is to replace words with 'Words' for example, regardless of current capitalization, I want to capitalize or lowercase certain words. some words will remain the same. My comment earlier denotes the use of a flag to capture all words on page without regard to capitalization and the use the value of the name, value pairs to place the value I want.